# CSS overwritten

Tags: css

I've a blog at http://olisan.dk/blog/ - as You can see there's a 28px high gap (margin-top)... In the style.css:

`margin-top: 0;` was also set to `margin-top: 0 !important;` none of these worked as desired - I can see `margin-top: 28px !important` in FireBug, located in "blog #2" (!??)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is this large gap? I cannot see it in chrome?

Comment: Safari says its `padding-top: 20px; margin-top: 0px;` for me

Comment: No gap/margin in FF4 and IE8 either.

Comment: Which browser are you looking at it in? Which element is reporting this margin?

Answer (score 2):

Since none of us are seeing this gap, I'm assuming that it's the admin bar for wordpress that's adding the gap on top. You can remove this if you're not using it in your theme.

```
wp_deregister_script('admin-bar');
wp_deregister_style('admin-bar');
remove_action('wp_footer','wp_admin_bar_render',1000);
```

http://italkless.com/remove-wordpress-3-1-admin-bar-easily.html

Answer (score 1):

Line 194 of style.css has the following

```
#topbody {
    width: 939px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Change to...

```
#topbody {
    width: 939px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Will get rid of the white gap on the top.

Answer (score 0):

..locate your header.php, and just after the wp_head call, paste the following code
`<style type="text/css" media="screen">
                html { margin-top: 0px !important; }
                * html body { margin-top: 0px !important; }
                </style>`